# AngularJS First Load with themes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this website that I have created that has themes that a user can select. The Themes are loaded through CSS files and are activated by selecting a theme from the account settings page.
This is how they are loaded on the page:

```
<link href="css/themes/default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" ng-if="settings.active === 'default' || !settings.theme">
<link href="css/themes/blue-hoki.min.css" rel="stylesheet" ng-if="settings.active === 'blue-hoki'" />
<link href="css/themes/blue-steel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" ng-if="settings.active === 'blue-steel'" />
<link href="css/themes/green-haze.min.css" rel="stylesheet" ng-if="settings.active === 'green-haze'" />
<link href="css/themes/purple-plum.min.css" rel="stylesheet" ng-if="settings.active === 'purple-plum'" />
<link href="css/themes/purple-studio.min.css" rel="stylesheet" ng-if="settings.active === 'purple-studio'" />
<link href="css/themes/red-intense.min.css" rel="stylesheet" ng-if="settings.active === 'red-intense'" />
<link href="css/themes/red-sunglo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" ng-if="settings.active === 'red-sunglo'" />
<link href="css/themes/yellow-crusta.min.css" rel="stylesheet" ng-if="settings.active === 'yellow-crusta'" />
```

As you can see I am using **ng-if** which works, but there is an issue. The default theme is selected if there are not themes or the active theme is **default**. The problem is, for a split second when the page loads for the first time, no settings have been loaded so it flickers with the default theme until the settings have been loaded.

To get the settings, I use **$stateChangeStart** like this:

```
// On state change
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams) {

    // Caused each state change to scroll to the top of the page
    document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;

    // Get our data
    var data = toState.data; // Get our state data
    var requireLogin = typeof data === 'undefined' ? false : data.requireLogin; // Check to see if we have any data and if so, check to see if we need login rights
    var user = account.current(); // This is set in our account service

    // Set our rootScope user
    $rootScope.user = user;

    // If we require login rights and we are not authenticated
    if (user && !user.authenticated && requireLogin) {

        // Stop processing
        event.preventDefault();

        // Get our current state
        var name = toState.name;
        var params = toParams;

        // If our state is the login page (i.e. we accessed it directly)
        if (name === 'login') {

            // Set our state to the homepage
            name = 'home';
            toParams = {
            };
        }

        // redirect to the login page and pass the state parameter
        $state.transitionTo('login', { returnState: name, returnParams: params });
    }

    // If we have some settings
    if ($rootScope.settings) {

        // Set our active theme to our company theme
        $rootScope.settings.active = $rootScope.settings.theme;
    }

    // If we have a user and the companyId has not been set
    if (user && user.authenticated && !$rootScope.settings) {

        // Get our company id
        var companyId = user.companyId;

        // Get our company
        companyService.get(companyId).then(function (response) {

            // Create our settings object
            var settings = {
                theme: response.theme,
                active: response.theme,
                logo: response.logo,
                companyName: response.name
            };

            // Add to our rootScope
            $rootScope.settings = settings;
        });
    }
});
```

I need to come up with a way to hide the page until the settings have loaded or do something else to stop the flicker. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: May be try use ng-init=" settings.active = 'default' " on the default  style <link>? So maybe it get initialize instantly ?

Comment: Is [ng-cloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) of any use to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, So I tried to solve this myself.
First I created a new loading element:

```
.loading {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 20000;
    background-color: #FFF;
    transition: all ease 1s;
    opacity: 1;

    &.fade-out {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

And I added it to the page like this:

```
<div class="loading" ng-class="{ 'fade-out': finishedLoading }">
</div>
```

Then in the **$rootScope** I set a variable before any event based functions (so it will be set the first time the app loads):

```
$rootScope.finishedLoading = false;
```

Then I adjusted my code to do this:

```
// If we have some settings (This will reset the theme when previewing from company settings)
if ($rootScope.settings) {

    // Set our active theme to our company theme
    $rootScope.settings.active = $rootScope.settings.theme;

    // We are not loading
    $rootScope.finishedLoading = true;
}

// If we have a user and the companyId has not been set
if (user && user.authenticated && !$rootScope.settings) {

    // Get our company id
    var companyId = user.companyId;

    // Get our company
    companyService.get(companyId).then(function (response) {

        // Create our settings object
        var settings = {
            theme: response.theme,
            active: response.theme,
            logo: response.logo,
            companyName: response.name
        };

        // Add to our rootScope
        $rootScope.settings = settings;

        // We are not loading
        $rootScope.finishedLoading = true;
    });
}
```

After the first time it is set to true, it is never set to false again, so this only happens when my page is initially loaded.
This seems to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the page loads before the angular controller is done. So settings.theme=undefined what in JavaScript is like false. If you remove !settings.theme in the default themes ng-if I think it will work. You have the same problem when u use strings in the view with {{ctr.somestring}}. The first second you see {{ctr.somestring}} in the View instead of the string.

Comment: removing !settings.theme has the same issue. I will udpate my question to show how I set the theme.